# On emptiness of certain $G^r_d(X)$ on a smooth plane curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $X$ be a smooth plane projective curve of degree $6$ and genus $10$ (over complex numbers). Then my question is the following :

**Question :** Is it possible that there exists a special divisor $D$ of degree $9$ on $X$ admitting exactly $4$ independent sections?

**Observations :** $(i)$ From Clifford's theorem: we have, $h^0(\mathcal O_X(D)) -1 =3\leq \frac{\text{deg}(D)}{2} =4.5$. Therefore, this theorem says that such divisor may exists on $X$.

$(ii)$ Note that, if such a divisor exists on $X$, then it belongs to $G^3_9(X)$. Since, $\rho(10,3,9)=-6<0$, we can't guarantee the non-emptiness of $G^3_9(X)$.

Any insight or remark from anyone is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Let $H$ be the divisor of a line. Use  the base point free pencil trick to get an exact sequence
$$0\rightarrow H^0(D-H)\rightarrow H^0(D)^2\rightarrow H^0(D+H)$$
Since $\deg(D+H)=15$, we have by Riemann-Roch $h^0(D+H)\leq 7$, hence $h^0(D-H)\geq 1$. Thus $D\equiv H+E$ with $E\geq 0$ of degree 3. But by Serre duality, $h^0(H+E)=h^0(2H-E)$. Now $E$ imposes independent conditions on conics, so $h^0(2H-E)=h^0(2H)-3=3$, contradicting $h^0(D)=4$.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. From one of your answer to one of my previous question I already reached upto $h^0(H+E)=h^0(2H-E)$. But then from the fact that $E$ imposes independent conditions on conics....could you please briefly explain why are we having the relation $h^0(2H-E)= h^0(2H)-3$?...does it follows from twisting and then taking long exact sequence to the standard short exact sequence for the divisor on a variety? Or is it something else?..may be I'm missing something obvious there.

Comment: The system $\lvert 2H\rvert$ is cut down by conics in $\mathbb{P}^2$, so $\lvert 2H-E\rvert$ is cut down by conics passing through $E$. Now any length 3 subscheme of $\mathbb{P}^2$ imposes 3 conditions on conics — see Lemma 0.1.1 in Beltrametti-Sommese *Zero cycles and $k$-th order embeddings of smooth projective surfaces*,  INDAM Symposia Mathematica, 32,(1992), 33-48.

Comment: thank you very much. I will surely try to relate with the result you mentioned.

Comment: it appears that the paper that you mentioned is not available online. could you please mention some other reference where the result appears? Does this lemma appear in the book " the adjunction theory of complex projective varieties" by the same authors?

Comment: if $D$ has degree $8$, then $E$ has degree $2$ and therefore the above technique does not yield any contradiction...right? please correct me if this is wrong.

Comment: What is your question if $\deg(D)=8$? You can have $h^0=3$, and certainly not 4 — the exact sequence would give you a $g^1_2$.

Comment: my question is that when $D$ is of degree $8$ can it admit exactly $4$ sections?....Do you mean $E$ is $g^1_2$ in this case?...but following your argument it has atleast one section and being on a degree $6$ curve it can't have $2$ or more sections...if it's a degree $2$ zero cycle on $\mathbb P^2$ and imposes independent conditions on conics...then following your argument isn't it $h^0=6-2=4$. How $E$ being $g^1_2$ implies the section is $3$ and not $4$?

Comment: $E$ cannot be a $g^1_2$, $X$ would be hyperelliptic.

Comment: that's what I mentioned that $E$ has exactly $1$ section and thus it can't be a $g^1_2$ .But in one of your previous comment you mentioned that from some short exact sequence we will get a $g^1_2$  and number of sections must be $3$ and not $4$ . Could you please briefly explain Where from we are getting a $g^1_2$? and why the number of section is $3$ and not $4$?

Comment: If it is 4, $D+p$ for any $p\in X$ contradicts my previous answer.

Comment: do you mean if there exists $D$ with degree $8$ and having $4$ sections, then $D+p$ is a divisor with degree $9$  and having $4$ sections, a contradiction to your previous answer? In that case inductively this means there can't exist a divisor of degree $ \leq 9$ on $X$ having exactly $4$ section (please correct me if this is wrong)

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean.

Comment: thank you very much. Could you please suggest an alternative reference related to the lemma you mentioned in your answer?. I tried to find the  paper  mentioned by you, but it's not available online.

Comment: Sorry I don't have time to look foor another reference. In your case, the proof is very easy, and a good exercise.

Comment: Can we say something regarding non-existence in this case if degree of $D$ remains the same(i.e $\text{deg}(D)=9$ but section is lesser i.e respectively $2$ and $3$. Indeed the above technique then does not apply. For section $3$ we have $\rho = -2$ and for $2$ we have $\rho=2$.

Comment: Take $H+ 3$ points.

Comment: then $H+3$ has degree $9$ and section $3$ right? what about section $2$ and except this can we construct any other such divisor?

Comment: I will stop the discussion here. I think that [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9301003.pdf) might help.

Comment: thank you very much for the reference.